# Найти расстояние между первым и последним максимальным элементом массива

Tags: c#

не могу добить до конца, дошла до вывода номеров всех максимальных чисел, но найти расстояние между первым и последним не выходит. Заранее спасибо за помощь

```
Random r = new Random();
        int[] nums = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            nums[i] = r.Next(0, 11);
        Console.WriteLine("Random array");
        foreach (int x in nums)
        {
            Console.Write($"{x} ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
       
        int maxi = nums[0];
        int mini = nums[0];
        int max = -1;
        int index1 = -1;
        int index2 = -1;
        // Цикл по всем элементам массива
        // От 0 до размера массива
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
            if (max <= nums[i])
            {
                // Запоминаем новое максимальное значение
                max = nums[i];
                // Запоминаем порядковый номер
                index1 = i;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
            if (nums[i] == max)
            {
                index2 = i;
                Console.WriteLine("Номер максимального числа: " + index2);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Как в массиве может быть несколько максимальных чисел? Они одинаковые? А если нет одинаковых максимальных, то есть оно только одно? А так, если в лоб, то в самом низу добавьте строчку `Console.WriteLine(index2 - index1);`

Comment: растояние будет расчитываться так: length = index2-index1; по модулю)

Comment: Последний максимальный - это минимальный что ли?

Comment: @aepot выводит 0 в таком варианте Console.WriteLine(index2 - index1); если одно максимальное, то 0 так как расстояния соответственно нет

Comment: @tym32167 если в последовательности несколько максимальных одинаковых значений, то нужно посчитать расстояние между первым и последним максимальным, если  если одно максимальное, то 0 так как расстояния соответственно нет

Answer (score 0):

Небольшая модификация, а второй цикл не нужен

```
 int index1 = 0;
 int index2 = 0;
 for (int i = 1; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
            if (nums[index1] < nums[i])
            {   // Запоминаем порядковый номер
                index1 = i;
                index2 = i;
            }
            else if (nums[index1] == nums[i])
                index2 = i;
        }
 вывести index2-index1
```